# Jars disappear from Tomcat7 lib folder

Tags: jar, tomcat7, missing-data

I have a Java EE web project in Eclipse and a Tomcat7 installation on my Windows 7 PC.

Occasionally, some of the `jersey-server jars` disappear from the lib folder in the Tomcat7 installation.  Sometimes it's other jars.  If I copy the missing jars back into the lib folder from elsewhere and restart tomcat in Eclipse, my services will work again, otherwise they encounter the infamous `class not found` error when tomcat starts.

This occurs on my `localhost` server in a dev environment.  I am the only user of this dev machine and I don't remove them - but something is.

What I am doing, or not doing that causes the jars to get removed from the lib folder?  i just want to get to the bottom of why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has nothing to do with java or tomcat7. If someone else manages your server (Server admin), you should consult with him. Probably you have an aggressive paranoid antivirus !

Try using [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to investigate such behavior.

Comment: Perhaps I should have made clear this happens on my local dev machine.  I am the admin - and I assure you I don't remove them.  Perhaps MS Security Essentials is doing it?

Comment: May be, but it just can't be java or Tomcat7. May be you could use (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to examine such behavior.

Comment: Is there any way to test that theory?

Answer (score 0):

In most probability, Eclipse Server plugin causes this. Based on you web-project configuration in Eclipse at the time of deployment it manages web-project artifacts in associated server directories.
Checkout web-project build path, runtime setting and Tomcat7 integration configuration in your Eclipse.

Comment: Nothing looks out of the ordinary.  Should I be looking for something in particular?